# How to get a reference to a Svelte component from within the component

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

There's an easy way to get a reference to an instance of a sub component from the parent scope, as shown [in the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-this).

What I want is to get a reference to the component from within the component itself. So, if we were looking at the official Svelte demo linked above, I would be meaning that I want a reference to the InputField instance from within the InputField instance, rather than from App.svelte.

(The reason I want this: I need instances to fire hooks to external JS libraries that will interract with the instance programmatically.)

### Copy of code from tutorial (for convenience and longevity)

App.svelte:

```html
<script>
    import InputField from './InputField.svelte';
    let field;
</script>
<InputField bind:this={field}/>
<button on:click={() => field.focus()}>Focus field</button>
```

InputFiled.svelte:

```html
<script>
    let input;
    export function focus() {
        input.focus();
    }

    // Somewhere here, I want a var, like you might imagine the following to do:
    let myself = this;
</script>
<input bind:this={input} />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a refrence from the parent and pass it the child:

```
<script>
    import InputField from './InputField.svelte';
    let field;
</script>

<InputField bind:this={field} {field}/>

<button on:click={() => field.focus()}>Focus field</button>
```

once you get the field pass it to the input

```
<script>
    let input;
        export let field;
    export function focus() {
        input.focus();
    }
        let myself;
        $:if(field) myself = field;
</script>
<input bind:this={input} />
```

and you can use it with context.

Comment: I did think that might be an option (seems odd to have to do this though!). What did you mean by "you can use it with context"?

Comment: @artfulrobot create a context with the field and usecontext in input, just a way to tidy things up and not oddly pass it to the component and be able to use it anywhere.

Comment: Ah, yeah, ok, thanks very much.